# Problem in SwiftUI with views getting redrawn, interrupting animation

Tags: swiftui

The following code displays a number that is increased every second, along with 5 circles that animate between blue and red colors:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1.0, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    
    @State private var num = 0
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(num)")
                .onReceive(timer) { _ in
                    num += 1. //commenting this line out allows the CirclesView to keep animating properly.
                }
            CirclesView()
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}

struct CirclesView: View {
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1.0, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    @State private var colorOn = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(0...5, id: \.self) { n in
            CircleView(size: 30, isOn: n % 2 == 0 ? colorOn : !colorOn)
            
                .onReceive(timer) { _ in
                    colorOn.toggle()
                }
        }
    }
}

struct CircleView: View {
    var size: CGFloat
    var isOn: Bool

    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .fill(isOn ? .red : .blue)
            .frame(width: size, height: size)
            .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.5), value: isOn)
    }
}
```

The problem is (I think) that the ContentView is redrawn every time the timer ticks because `num` is a @State var. If I don't update `num` in the onReceive modifier, the circles animate properly, but if I do update `num`, the Circles keep getting redrawn before they have a chance for their own timer to run.

Is it possible to have the CirclesView not get redrawn? I need its animation to continue to run and not be interrupted when some other state in ContentView changes. Or what is the right way to go about having views that should not be updated due to some continuous animation that should happen? Is the only way to do it to have some entirely different view "own" the CirclesView so that it's not affected?

Comment: You should look at `TimelineView`, `Timer` is not the best solution with SwiftUI. It is filled with issues since Views are value types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main issues with the code:

1. When you declare your `Timer` as a `let` property on the `View`, whenever that View gets re-evaluated, the `Timer` gets recreated. If you want the `Timer` to continue through re-evaluations, you need to store it. You could use `@State` for that.
2. You have your `.onReceive(timer)` on *each* `CircleView`. I think that you'll find that if you run the code as provided, it doesn't produce the results you want even with that line commented.

Here's a simple example with those elements adjusted:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1.0, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    
    @State private var num = 0
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(num)")
                .onReceive(timer) { _ in
                    num += 1
                }
            CirclesView()
        }
    }
}

struct CirclesView: View {
    @State private var timer = Timer.publish(every: 1.0, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    @State private var colorOn = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(0...5, id: \.self) { n in
            CircleView(size: 30, isOn: n % 2 == 0 ? colorOn : !colorOn)
        }
        .onReceive(timer) { _ in
            colorOn.toggle()
        }
    }
}

struct CircleView: View {
    var size: CGFloat
    var isOn: Bool

    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .fill(isOn ? .red : .blue)
            .frame(width: size, height: size)
            .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.5), value: isOn)
    }
}
```

#### Modern code

That being said, a more modern, SwiftUI-y approach would be to use a `task` and async/await rather than the `Timer`/Combine approach. Here's what that would look like:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var num = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(num)")
            CirclesView()
        }
        .task {
            while !Task.isCancelled {
                try? await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(1))
                num += 1
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CirclesView: View {
    @State private var colorOn = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(0...5, id: \.self) { n in
            CircleView(size: 30, isOn: n % 2 == 0 ? colorOn : !colorOn)
        }
        .task {
            while !Task.isCancelled {
                try? await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(1))
                colorOn.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

#### Equatable `View`, just to prove a point

Finally, just for kicks, here's further proof about the re-evaluation of the original view and the `let` `Timer`. I *do not* recommend doing this, but you can force the view to not re-evaluate by conforming to `Equatable`, and telling the system that the views are always equal. Then, they won't be re-evaluated when the parent is.

```
struct CirclesView: View {
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1.0, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    @State private var colorOn = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(0...5, id: \.self) { n in
            CircleView(size: 30, isOn: n % 2 == 0 ? colorOn : !colorOn)
        }
        .onReceive(timer) { _ in
            colorOn.toggle()
        }
    }
}

extension CirclesView: Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: CirclesView, rhs: CirclesView) -> Bool {
        true
    }
}

struct CircleView: View {
    var size: CGFloat
    var isOn: Bool

    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .fill(isOn ? .red : .blue)
            .frame(width: size, height: size)
            .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.5), value: isOn)
    }
}
```

The above is for learning only! The recommended approach is the async/await in the second code block.

Comment: :mind-blown-emoji. This indeed works. But why does modifying num in this way (in a Task) cause only the Text object to update and not CirclesView? How is it acting differently than `onReceive`?

Comment: A Task is used in both views. The important bit is that the Timer isn’t getting recreated on every re-evaluation

Comment: Forget both views for a minute. Why does `Task` in ContentView only force a redraw of Text() in the VStack and not CirclesView()? While `onReceive` forces a redraw of both.

Comment: I don't see any evidence of that. If you use a `Task` in ContentView and stick with the `let Timer` in CirclesView, you'll still see your original behavior.