# View body contents updating every time any property is changed

Tags: swiftui

Xcode version 15.2 (15C500b)

Related: [Problem in SwiftUI with views getting redrawn, interrupting animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78134228/problem-in-swiftui-with-views-getting-redrawn-interrupting-animation)

My expectation, based on Apple's WWDC talks on `View` "identity", is that when one property in a SwiftUI `View` changes, it shouldn't necessarily cause a draw update of another, unrelated `View`.

**Problem:** changing the value of one property (a `TimerPublisher`) does cause the refresh of an unrelated `View`.

In the following example, a `Timer` fires once every second, updating a `Date`. This causes a `Text` view to update accordingly. So far so good.

However, a **second** `Text` view also changes.

This can be seen by applying a randomly colored `background` to the second Text view. In this case, the background color of "Hello, World" will change once a second.

```
struct TestView: View {

    @State private var date = Date.now
    @State private var timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    
    var body: some View {
    
        VStack {
            Text(date.formatted())
                .onReceive(timer) { newDate in
                    date = newDate
                }
            
            Text("Hello, World")
                .background(Color.random) // This changes when 'timer' publishes!
        }
    }
}

extension Color {
    static var random: Color {
        return Color(
            red: .random(in: 0...1),
            green: .random(in: 0...1),
            blue: .random(in: 0...1)
        )
    }
}

#Preview {
    TestView()
}
```

[image]

Is this expected behaviour? Are my assumptions incorrect, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is the Solution :**

To stop rendering other components in a given Body View. Create struct  **DateUpdateView**,  This ensures that it does **not update other components** when the timer fires. Only the **DateUpdateView** updates its content when the timer fires.

```
import SwiftUI
        
        struct TestView: View {
            var body: some View {
            
                VStack {
                    DateUpdateView()
                
                    // onReceive method will not effect or render below  Text.
                    Text("Hello, World")
                        .background(Color.random) // This changes when 'timer' publishes!
                }
            }
        }
        
         // MARK: DateUpdateView  Update on onRecieve Method
        struct DateUpdateView : View {
            @State private var date = Date.now
            @State private var timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
            
            var body: some View {
                Text(date.formatted())
                
                    .onReceive(timer) { newDate in
                        date = newDate
                    }
            }
        }
        
        
        extension Color {
            static var random: Color {
                return Color(
                    red: .random(in: 0...1),
                    green: .random(in: 0...1),
                    blue: .random(in: 0...1)
                )
            }
        }
        
        #Preview {
            TestView()
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I've made an example. Let's say if `TestView` really needs to re-render its entire body or not

```swift
var body: some View {
  VStack {
    VStack {
      Text(date...)

      Text("Hello, World")
        .background(Color.random)  
    }

    Text("Hello, World from outside")
      .background(Color.random)  
  }

  Text("Outside of outside Hello, World")
            .background(Color.random)
}
```

The same result happened, all three `Text`s changed the background color even if it wasn't relevant to themselves. However, let's try some more: break out into another view and keep the code as it is.

```swift
struct HiView: View {
  var body: some View {
    Text("Hi there!")
      .background(Color.random)
    }
}
```

Then put it into `TestView` above

```swift
var body: some View {
  VStack {
    VStack {
      HiView()      

      Text(date...)
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

[image]

---

Conclusion: SwiftUI manages views state with graph data structure under the hood via `identity` (according to Demystify SwiftUI WWDC's video). IMHO, a view is a single Node in the whole graph. All sub-views inside this node will stick together until it splits up into another struct, let's say another Node.